# hasManyThrough many to many in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models:

```
Product
Inventory
Order
```

The relationship between them like:

Order has manyToMany relationship with Inventory and $nventory->belongsTo('product');

```
/** Product Model **/
class Product extend Model 
{

    public function inventories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Inventory');
    }
}

/** Inventory Model **/
class Inventory extend Model 
{

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}

/** Order Model **/
class Order extend Model {

    public function inventories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Inventory','order_items');
    }


    //how do I get this?
    public function products()
    {

    }
}
```

The `hasManyThrough` will not work because of the `order_items` pivot table. How can I get the products of a order?

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with support for `BelongsToMany`: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Order extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Product::class,
            ['order_items', Inventory::class],
            [null, null, 'id'],
            [null, null, 'product_id']
        );
    }
}
```